# Bundle Cython module with a Python package

Tags: python, cython, packaging

I'm wrapping a C++ library in Cython, and I would like to distribute this as a Python package. I've been using [this tutorial](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) as a guide.

Here is how things are organized.

```
.
├── inc
│   └── Rectangle.h
├── rect
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── wrapper.pyx
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── Rectangle.cpp
```

I've pasted the contents of these files at the bottom of the post, as well as in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/standage/cython-packaging-demo).

I have no problem compiling and installing with `python setup.py install`, and I can `import rect` from the interpreter with no problem. But it seems to be an empty class: I can't create a `Rectangle` object with any of the following.
- `Rectangle`
- `rect.Rectangle`
- `wrapper.Rectangle`
- `rect.wrapper.Rectangle`

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Contents of `Rectangle.h`, copied and pasted from the tutorial.

```
namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
    public:
        int x0, y0, x1, y1;
        Rectangle();
        Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
        ~Rectangle();
        int getArea();
        void getSize(int* width, int* height);
        void move(int dx, int dy);
    };
}
```

Contents of `Rectangle.cpp`.

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

namespace shapes {

  Rectangle::Rectangle() { }

    Rectangle::Rectangle(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1) {
        x0 = X0;
        y0 = Y0;
        x1 = X1;
        y1 = Y1;
    }

    Rectangle::~Rectangle() { }

    int Rectangle::getArea() {
        return (x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0);
    }

    void Rectangle::getSize(int *width, int *height) {
        (*width) = x1 - x0;
        (*height) = y1 - y0;
    }

    void Rectangle::move(int dx, int dy) {
        x0 += dx;
        y0 += dy;
        x1 += dx;
        y1 += dy;
    }

}
```

Cython wrapper code `wrapper.pyx`.

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = src/Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle() except +
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getArea()
        void getSize(int* width, int* height)
        void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle c_rect      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.c_rect = Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def get_area(self):
        return self.c_rect.getArea()
    def get_size(self):
        cdef int width, height
        self.c_rect.getSize(&width, &height)
        return width, height
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.c_rect.move(dx, dy)
```

The `setup.py` script I've adapted for this file organization.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='rect',
    packages=['rect'],
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
        'Rectangle',
        sources=['rect/wrapper.pyx', 'src/Rectangle.cpp'],
        include_dirs=['inc/'],
        language='c++',
        extra_compile_args=['--std=c++11'],
        extra_link_args=['--std=c++11']
    )),
)
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [thearn's simple cython example](https://github.com/thearn/simple-cython-example). It partially looks like there may be an issue with your `setup.py` because you have the `Extension` as `Rectangle` which causes there to be a `Rectangle.so` created within `python/site-packages`. You will also want to change your `__init__.py` so it imports your classes from your `Rectangle.so/wrapper` and also the name of the extension to be `rect.Rectangle` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem turned out to be that the `.pyx` file and the extension did not have the same basename. When I renamed `wrapper.pyx` to `Rectangle` and re-installed I was able to run the following in the Python interpreter.

```
>>> import Rectangle
>>> r = Rectangle.PyRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
>>> r.get_area()
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement acts on `__init__.py` which is probably empty
But what your setup script should create is an `.so` file. Thus you have to run it not with `install` but with `build_ext` (and `--inplace`) which gives you the `.so` file that can be then imported. But be careful with your names in `setup.py` you will end up with several possible items to be imported when calling `import rect`. Avoid that the name of the extension is the same as the package (or modify afterwards the `__init__.py` file accordingly)

Comment: The `build_ext` task is invoked when I run `python setup.py install`, and an `.so` file is created (in the `build/` directory) and installed. Running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` creates the file in the root directory. Can you clarify how this helps me?

Comment: I suspect the basic problem is still the name choice. You have a `rect.so` file and a `rect` folder with an `__init__.py` file in it. And you end up with the import of the empty module instead of your `rect.so` file. As I said I assume a change of the extension name would solve this ambiguity and with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` you have the module at the root directory so no need to extend PYTHONPATH or doing anything in addition.

Comment: Ok, it turns out that I can `import Rectangle` after running `python setup.py install`, but I get the following warning: `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_Rectangle)`. It's the same when I build in place without installing.